# Sort `.bash_history` by timestamp

Tags: bash, sorting

I've enabled the timestamp for my `.bash_history` by using the `HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d.%m.%y %T "` instructive in `.bashrc`. However, sometimes the order of the entries in the `.bash_history` is messed up, and I want to sort that file by the timestamp. Unfortunately, the timestamp is not in the same line as the entry, but one line above, like this:

```
#1512649029
a command
#1512649032
another command
#1512649039
a third command
```

So how can I sort the file by these "pairs" of lines? Furthermore, there are entries that have no timestamps, e.g. lines that have no `#...` line above. I want these lines to gather at the top of the file. Thanks!

Comment: Note that, depending on the implementation, .bash_history can contain binary (non-text) data. Test with file .bash_history.

Comment: It's `.bash_history: UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines` for me, so no binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: This might not be the most elegant and simplest solution.
However the following bash shell script snippet worked for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
function BashHistoryJoinTimestampLines() {
    COMMAND_WITHOUT_TIMESTAMP=TRUE
    while read line; do 
        if [ "${line:0:1}" = "#" ] # This should be a timestamp line
        then echo -ne "$line\t" # the -n option supresses the line feed
             COMMAND_WITHOUT_TIMESTAMP=FALSE
        else if [ ${COMMAND_WITHOUT_TIMESTAMP} = TRUE ]
             then echo -ne "#0\t"
             fi
             echo $line
             COMMAND_WITHOUT_TIMESTAMP=TRUE
        fi
    done 
}
#
# Example:
BashHistoryJoinTimestampLines < $HISTFILE | sort
```

In Unix/Linux text processing by pipelining the `sort` utility program by default operates on records separated by line endings.

In order to use "`sort`" for this application the timestamp lines have to be first joined together with the history lines containing the commands. Lines not preceeded by a time stamp will get a dummy timestamp of `#0` (January 1st 1970) in this script. I've used the TAB character as a separator between timestamp and command in this script.

Comment: Really, we should be using `sort -n` to account for old datestamps (yes, I do remember the rollover to ten-digit times) and future ones (I don't expect to live that long!)

Comment: @toby-speight: your objection applies to commands recorded before 9-9-2001 or after 20-11-2286. However: Most people I know won't record their shell commands that long.

Answer (score 2):

We can use a simple `sed` program to join lines:

```sed
/^$/d            # skip blank lines
/^#/N            # append next line to timestamp
/^#/!s/^/#0\n/   # command without timestamp - prefix with #0
s/#//            # remove initial #
y/\n/ /          # convert newline to space
```

and another to restore the timestamp comments:

```sed
s/(\S+) /#\1\n/
```

Putting that all together, we get

```
sort_history() {
    sed -e '/^$/d' -e '/^#/N' -e '/^#/!s/^/#0\n/' \
        -e 's/#//' -e 'y/\n/ /' <<<"$in" \
      | sort -n | sed -e 's/\(\S\+\) /#\1\n/'
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks nice! Unfortunately, I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if there's an error somewhere, but I get an empty result when calling:
`in=".bash_history"; sed -e '/^$/d' -e '/^#/N' -e '/^#/!s/^/#0\n/' -e 's/#//' -e 'y/\n/ /' <<<"$in" | sort -n | sed -e 's/ \(\S\+\) /#\1\n/'`: `0 .bash_history`

Comment: You're passing the name of the file as the input, rather than its contents.  You probably meant `<"$in"`, not `<<<"$in"`.

Answer (score 0):

For a long time I looked for a way to merge bash history (with timestamps), and nothing seemed acceptable.

That is... Merge the on-disk ".bash_history" with the in-memory shell 'history'. Preserving timestamp ordering, and command order within those timestamps.

Optionally removing unique commands (even if multi-line), and/or removing (cleaning out) simple and/or sensitive commands, according to defined perl RE's. Adjust to suit!

This is the result... https://antofthy.gitlab.io/software/history_merge.bash.txt

Enjoy.